# How to test basicfwd application in DPDK

Tags: dpdk

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine with Kernel 4.4 and DPDK version 17.11.  I managed to configure igb_uio drivers using setup utility.

Then I compiled basicfwd application DPDK. I also configured two ports with igb_uio driver and verified that it's associated with DPDK and not shown in Linux Kernel.

basicfwd application is listening on two ports where MAC address is displayed.

I am not sure how to send packet for MAC address. Can anyone suggest how to create packets for given MAC address using a command or utility. Windows is host OS in my laptop.

I also see PMD application and packetgen application are used for testing  purpose. I am not sure whether they can be used to test basicfwd application.

Also I would like to know How to assign ip address for DPDK port so that they can receive packets in live environment. I need to study more on DPDK on these aspects.

Would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: please accept and upvote as it solves your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DPDK is an alternative for Kernel stack Processing, so any ports bound to DPDK via `uio_pci_generic/vfio-pci/igb_uio` will not be supporting IPv4/IPv6 address as kernel netdev. Hence the expectation of **How to assign ip address for DPDK port** is incorrect.

With respect to sending packet into a virtual machine, there are a couple of combination

1. have complete NIC pass through to VM (PF/VF) - in this scenario, one needs to send a packet through the physical interface it.
2. have port representation like TAP/VETH-Pair passed as virtio interface - in this scenario on the host machine, there will be representation port. So you can use tools like `ping/arping/packeth/pktgen/scapy/ostinato` to generate packets for you.

Note: if you are using `testpmd` dpdk application you can make it run in Promiscuous mode. For examples like `l2fwd/skeleton` the ports are by default set into promiscuous mode.

Comment: Let me study and try TAP option. Can you please clarify if IP address can't be assigned to DPDK port how DPDK ports would receive packets from other systems/applications. Suppose I use it for Firewall or Webserver I am not sure how it works. It's supposed to carry ip address in packets.  is it something related to TAP  It seems there is a gap in my understanding. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I am happy to be on skype to spend some time on this. are you available?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am doing for learning purpose at beginner level. If you guide me on some references on this it would be great.

Comment: ok, looks like you are not ready to be on skype. Good, please always use http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/ and http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/index.html

Comment: please accept and upvote to close this ticket.

Comment: Will refer the links. Thanks for your support.